# Amend description of menu location in customizer Wordpress

Tags: theme-customizer

Amend description of menu locations in customizer? I just want to add note that I have limited menu depth. Not really sure how to do it.

I refer to this description under 'Menu Locations'

> Your theme supports 2 menus. Select which menu appears in each
>   location. You can also place menus in widget areas with the “Custom
>   Menu” widget.

or to add description for Menu panel.

I tried like this

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'nav_menus', array(
'description' => esc_html__( 'new description', 'theme_name' ),
) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be modifying a *section* not a *setting*.

Try this:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', function( $wp_customize ) {
    $section = $wp_customize->get_section( 'menu_locations' );
    $section->description .= "<p>Custom HTML added.</p>";
}, 12 );
```

The priority of `12` is used because `\WP_Customize_Nav_Menus::customize_register()` happens at priority `11`, and this is where the section is added.